# Can Impression Region data from SFMC emails be tracked in Salesforce in the Individual email result?

Tags: marketing-cloud, reporting, integration

We are looking to use salesforce reports in order to report on dynamic content within our emails. We have set up Impression Regions for our dynamic content, but were wondering if this data could be tracked in Salesforce via the Individual Email Result?

This way we can report at a subscriber level, rather than just through the impression region over time reports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This data is available via the data extract "Tracking Extract". There are the options to extract the following data/files:

- Extract Click Impressions
- Extract Send Impressions
- Extract Send Job Impressions

This is subscriber level reporting - so should give you what you need.